# react-router-dom v6 TypeScript withRouter for class components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I'm trying to update `react-router-dom` to **v6** in my **TypeScript React** app.

In the [offical react-router-dom documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5) is simply states:

> Along with the upgrade to v5.1, you should replace any usage of `withRouter` with hooks.

It completely ignore *class components*!

I searched for a long time on the internet, but all the articles I found

- speak about **JavaScript** rather than **TypeScript**, or
- speak about **function components**, or
- refer to **v5** (or lower) of `react-router-dom` since they speak about `withRouter`.

**Is there a well documented way to upgrade react-router-dom to v6 in a TypeScripp React app which doesn't require to refactor all class components into function components?**

Comment: You are correct, RRDv6 no longer exports a `withRouter` HOC. You can either convert your components to function components or create a custom `withRouter` HOC using the v6 hooks and injects the "route props" into the decorated components.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not well documented, but [this thread on GitHub](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8146#issuecomment-947860640) may give you the right direction to make this work. User mjackson suggests wrapping your class components in a HOC so you can wire the `withRouter` hook and your class components together.

```
// in hocs.js
function withNavigation(Component) {
  return props => <Component {...props} navigate={useNavigate()} />;
}

function withParams(Component) {
  return props => <Component {...props} params={useParams()} />;
}

// in BlogPost.js
class BlogPost extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let { id } = this.props.params;
    // ...
  }
}

export default withParams(BlogPost);
```

Comment: Can you explain how to do it in Typescript?